Unity Firebase Realtime Database - не могу получить данные из сервера на Android, хотя в Editor всё работает
В моём проекте подключён Firebase Realtime Database. В Editor всё работает превосходно, но при билде в apk данные из Firebase не приходят, хотя сохранение данных работает исправно.
Вот код сохранения и получения сохранений
public static async Task InitFirebase()
{
    await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance(app, "ссылка проекта в Firebase").RootReference;
    });
}

// Асинхронный метод для сохранения значения
public static async Task SaveFirebaseValue(string key, object value)
{
    await databaseReference.Child("Referrals_Data_2").Child(key).SetValueAsync(value);
}

// Асинхронный метод для получения значения
public static async Task<object> GetFirebaseValue(string key)
{
    object so = null;

    await databaseReference
    .Child("Referrals_Data_2").Child(key)
    .GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
          if (task.IsFaulted)
          {
              // Handle the error...
              so = 404;
          }
          else if (task.IsCompleted)
          {
              DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
              // Do something with snapshot...
              so = snapshot.GetValue(false);
          }
      });

    return so;
}

А, и ещё, забыл уточнить, что при получении значений на мобильном устройстве в LogCat выдаёт ошибку, а это скорее всего значит что проблема в этой строчке await databaseReference.Child("Referrals_Data_2").Child(key).GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread  ибо в противном случае мне бы не выдавало ошибку, а объект просто заменялся бы числом 404
